# How do I use a dependency on a Perl module installed in a non-standard location?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I need to install two Perl modules on a web host. Let's call them A::B and X::Y. X::Y depends on A::B (needs A::B to run). Both of them use [Module::Install](http://search.cpan.org?perldoc=Module::Install). I have successfully installed A::B into a non-system location using

```
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/non/system/location
make; make test; make install
```

Now I want to install X::Y, so I try the same thing

```
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/non/system/location
```

The output is

```
$ perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/non/system/location/
Cannot determine perl version info from lib/X/Y.pm
*** Module::AutoInstall version 1.03
*** Checking for Perl dependencies...
[Core Features]
- Test::More          ...loaded. (0.94)
- ExtUtils::MakeMaker ...loaded. (6.54 >= 6.11)
- File::ShareDir      ...loaded. (1.00)
- A::B                ...missing.
==> Auto-install the 1 mandatory module(s) from CPAN? [y]
```

It can't seem to find A::B in the system, although it is installed, and when it tries to auto-install the module from CPAN, it tries to write it into the system directory (ignoring PREFIX). I have tried using variables like `PERL_LIB` and `LIB` on the command line, after `PREFIX=...`, but nothing I have done seems to work.

I can do `make` and `make install` successfully, but I can't do `make test` because of this problem. Any suggestions?

I found some advice at http://servers.digitaldaze.com/extensions/perl/modules.html to use an environment variable PERL5LIB, but this also doesn't seem to work:

```
export PERL5LIB=/non/system/location/lib/perl5/
```

didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the following prescription did it:

```
perl Makefile.PL --skipdeps --no-manpages PREFIX=/non/system/location INSTALLSITELIB=/non/system/location/lib INSTALLSITEBIN=/non/system/location/bin INSTALLMAN1DIR=/non/system/location/man/man1 INSTALLMAN3DIR=/non/system/location/man/man3
```

This is just "monkey see monkey do" but now `make test` works.

- The `--skipdeps` option here suppresses a convenient feature/exasperating problem with Module::Install where it tries to use CPAN.pm to download missing modules.
- The `--no-manpages` is supposed to stop it installing man pages but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib), but you probably [already know that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067011/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-putting-the-perl-version-number-into-the-use-lib-line-f/3067086#3067086) :)

Comment: `local::lib` looks like a good solution here, but it involves another dependency, and it's not installed on the web host.

Comment: You can bootstrap local::lib into itself, if you can't install more libs to the standard location.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is the top link i thought i'd update with my experience (which has taken a while to get working, hence updating the 7 year old post).

first run  `perl -le 'print join $/, @INC'`

add (note, no / at the end!!) 
`export PERL5LIB=/nonstddir/scripts/modules/lib/site_perl:/nonstddir/scripts/modules/lib`

run  `perl -le 'print join $/, @INC'`   make sure the new dirs are added. this makes it work. if you add a / at the end of the path, the INC entry will look weird and wrong. Mine had a // in the middle.

When done and working, mine looks like

```
/nonstddir/scripts/modules/lib/site_perl/5.8.4/sun4-solaris-64int
/nonstddir/scripts/modules/lib/site_perl/5.8.4
/nonstddir/scripts/modules/lib/site_perl
/nonstddir/scripts/modules/lib/sun4-solaris-64int
/nonstddir/scripts/modules/lib
/usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int
/usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib
/usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4/sun4-solaris-64int
/usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4
/usr/perl5/site_perl
/usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4/sun4-solaris-64int
/usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4
/usr/perl5/vendor_perl
```