# Is there a way to avoid putting the Perl version number into the "use lib" line for Perl modules in non-standard locations?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to install some Perl modules into a non-standard location, let's call it `/non/standard/location`. I used

```
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/non/standard/location
make;make install
```

to install them.

In the script which uses the module, it seems to be necessary to specify a long directory path including the version of Perl, like so:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use lib '/non/standard/location/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/';
use A::B;
```

Is there any `use lib` or other statement which I can use which is not so long and verbose, and which does not include the actual version of Perl, in order that I don't have to go back and edit this out of the program if the version of Perl is upgraded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I have installed via the following prescription, which seems to fix things.

```
perl Makefile.PL --no-manpages --skipdeps PREFIX=/non/system/location INSTALLSITELIB=/non/system/location/lib INSTALLSITEBIN=/non/system/location/bin INSTALLMAN1DIR=/non/system/location/man/man1 INSTALLMAN3DIR=/non/system/location/man/man3
```

I welcome any constructive criticism of this. I want to use `--no-manpages` but the `INSTALLMAN1DIR` seems to be necessary anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not addressing all your questions, but do you know [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib)? When it’s available in the system perl, you can just `use local::lib`. If not:

```
use lib glob '~/perl5/lib/perl5';
use local::lib;
```

That’s probably a bit constraining – not sure how it works on Windows –, but it’s good enough for my purposes. Of course, if you can set up the environment before the script runs (`.bashrc`, `SetEnv` etc.), you can forget about the `use lib glob`, as the right path will be already set in `PERL5LIB`.

Comment: +1: I didn't know you could `use lib glob`. No more manually resolving `~` to an actual path!